# DRM security level on Android

Tags: java, android, drm, android-drm

How can I get the DRM security level programmatically within my app? 
I know there is a `acquireDrmInf` method but I cannot understand how to work with it in order to get the needed information.
I am trying to get it as described in https://support.google.com/widevine/answer/6072714?hl=en

Thanks

Comment: This example should help: https://github.com/NicePeopleAtWork/NicePlayers/blob/master/android/VideoView_MediaPlayer/NicePluginAndroidTest/src/com/widevine/demo/WidevineDrm.java